# New Galaxy Tab 2 10" backlight doesn't stay lit during use

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1, data-transfer

We are definitely newbies - can someone help?  We will be in full use of the tablet and the light goes dim.  It can happen shortly after we've turned it on, or it can be hours after play.  Doesn't seem right.  I have until tomorrow to return/exchange tablet, but my son has been leveling up in games that he doesn't want to lose.  Can we move the memory to a new one if we change it out?  How?  Or can we do something to fix it?  Thank you!!

Comment: As for the "levels", you might want to start with our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), which sums up available methods (and related questions with good answers). Concerning the screen, please take a look at our [screen timeout questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[screen]+timeout). After that, you probably want to update your question to make it more precise -- once you know what it's all about, rawly :)